# Scrapy XPath selector

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I am scraping [this site](http://mufmuf.ro/locuri-de-munca/joburi-in-strainatate) and I'm using Scrapy as the means. However, I am having trouble with the XPath. I'm not entirely sure what is going on:

Why does this work:

```
def parse_item(self, response):
    item = BotItem()

    for title in response.xpath('//h1'):
        item['title'] = title.xpath('strong/text()').extract()
        item['wage'] = title.xpath('span[@class="price"]/text()').extract()
        yield item
```

and the following code not?

```
def parse_item(self, response):
    item = BotItem()

    for title in response.xpath('//body'):
        item['title'] = title.xpath('h1/strong/text()').extract()
        item['wage'] = title.xpath('h1/span[@class="price"]/text()').extract()
        yield item
```

I aim to also extract the XPath for:

```
//div[@id="description"]/p
```

But I can't because it is outside the `h1` node. How can I achieve this? My full code is:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule

from bot.items import BotItem


class MufmufSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'mufmuf'
    allowed_domains = ['mufmuf.ro']
    start_urls = ['http://mufmuf.ro/locuri-de-munca/joburi-in-strainatate/']

    rules = (
        Rule(
            LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='//div[@class="paginate"][position() = last()]'), 
            #callback='parse_start_url', 
            follow=True
        ),
        Rule(
            LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='//h3/a'), 
            callback='parse_item', 
            follow=True
        ),

    def parse_item(self, response):
        item = BotItem()

        for title in response.xpath('//h1'):
            item['title'] = title.xpath('strong/text()').extract()
            item['wage'] = title.xpath('span[@class="price"]/text()').extract()
            #item['description'] = title.xpath('div[@id="descirption"]/p/text()').extract()
            yield item
```

Comment: Also note, you have a typo `descirption` -> `description`.

Comment: When you ask why one piece of code does "work" and the other doesn't, define what you mean: what did you expect the code to do, and what did it actually do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `for title in response.xpath('//body'):` option does not work because your XPath expressions in the loop make it search for `h1` element directly inside the `body` element.

Moreover, since there is only one desired entity to extract you don't need a loop here at all:

```
def parse_item(self, response):
    item = BotItem()

    item["title"] = response.xpath('//h1/strong/text()').extract()
    item["wage"] = response.xpath('//h1/span[@class="price"]/text()').extract()
    item["description"] = response.xpath('//div[@id="description"]/p/text()').extract()

    return item
```

(this should also answer your second question about the `description`)

Comment: Upvote for ditching the loop. I think you have an extra bracket on Line 6 `text())`